# Return an object if the value exists from an inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to return the object which hobbies is reading, below is my sample scenario

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "john",
        "hobbies": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "playing"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "peter",
        "hobbies": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "reading"
            }
        ]
    }
]

// Expected Output:
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "peter",
        "hobbies": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "reading"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I use filter() and find() method however i couldn't loop it inside hobbies array

Comment: Why ca you not?

Comment: Provide the excepted output with your attempts.

Comment: If you need a return as array then why your first line say about you need to a object in return.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
let arr = [ { "id": 1, "name": "john", "hobbies": [ { "id": 1, "name": "playing" } ] }, { "id": 2, "name": "mary", "hobbies": [ { "id": 2, "name": "cleaning" } ] }, { "id": 3, "name": "peter", "hobbies": [ { "id": 3, "name": "reading" } ] } ];
let res = arr.filter(x => x.hobbies.some(h => h.name === 'reading'));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You could have voted to close this question instead of answering a question which doesn't provides any relevant attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` method to `filter the outer array` and `Array.prototype.some` method to check if an object in the inner hobbies array `has a name property of "reading"`

```js
let people = [ { "id": 1, "name": "john", "hobbies": [ { "id": 1, "name": "playing" } ] }, { "id": 2, "name": "mary", "hobbies": [ { "id": 2, "name": "cleaning" } ] }, { "id": 3, "name": "peter", "hobbies": [ { "id": 3, "name": "reading" } ] } ];

let readingPerson = people.filter(person => 
  person.hobbies.some(hobby => hobby.name === "reading")
)[0];

console.log(readingPerson);
```